# logging javascript object properties

Tags: javascript

Please share your thoughts regarding below outputs.

```
var a = '';
console.log(a); //this logs nothing as expected.
a = 'triven';
```

[image: first log]

```
var a = {};
console.log(a); // How javascript is aware of property here that is defined below. 
a.name = 'triven';
```

[image]

Comment: mouse over the “i”

Comment: what's bugging you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `console.dir()`.

`console.log()` doesn't do what you want because it prints a reference to the object, and by the time you pop it open, it's changed. `console.dir` prints a directory of the properties in the object at the time you call it.

The JSON idea below is a good one; you could even go on to parse the JSON string and get a browsable object like what .dir() would give you:

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`

Comment: console.dir() is also giving me exactly same output as console.log() in latest chrome.

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); Tried this?

Comment: Yes this works fine.